# Import module with same package as existing one

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following directory structure:

```
/some/dir
       ┣ mainmodule
       ┃    ┣ __init__.py
       ┃    ┗ module.py
       ┗ submodules
            ┣ __init__.py
            ┗ module
                ┣ __init__.py
                ┣ submodule_1.py
                ┣ ...
                ┗ submodule_n.py
```

Both `/some/dir/mainmodule` and `/some/dir/submodules` are not on pyhton's library path. Being located in directory `/some/dir/mainmodule` I want to import all modules (`module.submodule_1`, ..., `module.submodule_n`) in directory `/some/dir/submodules`.

I tried the following. But I always get `ImportError: No module named submodule_1`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/some/dir/submodules")
>>> import module.submodule_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named submodule_1
>>>
```

The problem seems to be that `module.py` in `/some/dir/mainmodule` has the same name as the first package of the modules in `/some/dir/submodules`. Renaiming `module.py` or the package solves this issues, but as this is some widely used legacy code I'm working on, I don't know if there are undocumented references to these names. Thus I'm looking for a way to solve this without renaming any files.

Comment: try this sys.path.append(0, "/some/dir/submodules")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following line.

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/some/dir/submodules')
```